# How can I fix this jumbotron/carousel to be the size of the image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I would like to have a smaller jumbotron/carousel with the text over the images at the top of the page like I have, but I just don't like how plan it looks stretched across the whole width like that.

I would also like to know if there is a way to dim the image or put a transparent background behind the text so it is more visible?

I'm a newb developer trying to learn the ropes. I couldnt think of my own project to tackle, so I want to redesign my job's website in a "better" way. The website they currently have is not responsive. Just trying to learn the ropes more than anything. Here is my code.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Crabcake Factory | World Famous Cakes!</title>
   <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
  </head>
  <body>
               <!--navigation -->
                <div id="navmarg">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><p>Crabcake Factory | Online</p></a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">


                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Store <span class="caret"></span></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Clothing/Accessories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>

                          </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Locations &amp; Specials, Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Locations &amp; Specials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>

                          </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                      </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                </nav>
            </div>      
          <!--END NAV-->

  <!--SLIDESHOW-->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li class="active" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <div class="item active">            

                <div class="carousel-caption slidecenter">
                <h1>World Famous Cakes</h1>
                <p class="lead">Taste our world famous jumbo lump crabcakes!</p>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Order Crabcakes Anywhere</button>
                </div>


            <img src="img/crabcakes.jpg" alt="Crabcake Factory World Famous Jumbo Lump Crabcakes - Shipped Worldwide!" class="img-responsive slidecenter">


            </div>





          <div class="item">                        

                <div class="carousel-caption slidecenter">
                <h1>Something for everyone</h1>
                <p class="lead">Browse our menu!</p>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Menu</button>
                </div>

                <img src="img/cakeplate.jpg" alt="Crabcake Factory World Famous Jumbo Lump Crabcakes - Shipped Worldwide!" class="img-responsive slidecenter">
          </div>

          <div class="item">

                <div class=" carousel-caption slidecenter">
                <h1>Stop by during happy hour</h1>
                <p class="lead">Fenwick Happy Hour 12-6 | Best specials on the shore!</p>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Locations &amp; Specials</button>
                </div>

                 <img src="img/drinks.jpg" alt="Crabcake Factory World Famous drinks, fenwick de drink specials" class="img-responsive slidecenter">

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>

         <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
      </a>
      </a>
    </div>



  <!--END SLIDESHOW-->


    <div class="container">









  <div class="row">




    <!--EMAIL LIST-->

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 pull-right">
          <div id="email-list">
            <div class="widget widget-mailing-list" id="widget-mailing-list">

                      <div class="widget-header">
                        <h3>Stay up to date with Specials, Events and More!</h3>
                      </div>


                      <div class="widget-content">
                        <p>Sign up for online deals, news, events, specials, and more.</p>
                      </div>


                      <form action="//crabcakefactoryonline.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=6140fd91fdae3db6f79963c78&amp;id=207ed287eb" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
                        <input placeholder="your@email.com" name="EMAIL" id="email-input" type="email">
                        <input class="btn" value="Sign Up" name="subscribe" id="email-submit" type="submit">
                      </form>
            </div>      
          </div>

  <!-- END HEADER -->

      </div>
    <!--END EMAIL LIST -->
  </div>

















    </div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#myCarousel{

}


.slidecenter{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.item img{
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.carousel-indicators li{
    border-color: #222;

}

.carousel-indicators li.active{
    background-color: #222;
}
```

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle (http://www.jsFiddle.net)?

Comment: I made one but my site isn't showing correctly on it. The images aren't showing up

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=LSeuvc1arQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you are looking: [Bootsnipp Responsive Carousel](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-bs-carousel-with-hero-headers)

In case the link dies: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-bs-carousel-with-hero-headers it can be found searching www.bootsnipp.com for "Carousel".

The important aspects are located in [maridlcrmn's](http://bootsnipp.com/maridlcrmn) CSS file where she positions the hero absolute with percentages to maintain the text's position centrally to the view. You may have to crop your images since they are your company's for faster rendering.

**EDIT**

You mentioned your text overflowing. Chances are that some of your own styles are causing this as it doesn't occur in the example where the only files used are [Bootstrap CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) for CSS and JS, as well as and the [jQuery framework CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/). If it persists, there are media queries, targeting the text within the carousel. Add this to the end of your CSS for screen widths smaller than 340 pixels.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 340px) {
    .hero h1 {
        font-size:0.8em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I like how it looks. It's a lot of code I should probably attempt to examine. I've got something really nice looking going on, and I'm proud of it. But can't help but feel like I'm cheating with bootstrap :D

Comment: Now though, when I resize the page some text inside the carousel is being cut off :(

Comment: Welcome to Bootstrap. It's a wonderful framework to boost production time, but it helps to know the underlying CSS/HTML. I don't have the text cutting off.... Try excluding your own CSS files. They may be conflicting.

Comment: I don't know what could be causing it...

I took out all my css and it still cuts off. I just added less text to try to minimize the effect at small resolutions. It happens when I resize my browser to as small as it will go width wise

Comment: @AlexGray edited to make the font smaller when screen width is less than 340px.

Comment: awesome!

I tried using your media queries before, but what was wrong was that I put a separate CSS file with just the carousel CSS after my CSS file so it was over ridden.

I adjusted the size to 3em and it's good now! Thanks so much. Definitely learned a lot here

Comment: No worries, enjoy Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may stumble on this thread, here is how I fixed my problem:

I linked to a file containing this CSS, right before my custom CSS (Contains media queries to fix text)

```
/*
Fade content bs-carousel with hero headers
Code snippet by maridlcrmn (Follow me on Twitter @maridlcrmn) for Bootsnipp.com
Image credits: unsplash.com
*/

/********************************/
/*       Fade Bs-carousel       */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li {
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #f39c12;
    border-color: #f39c12;
    opacity: .7;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li.active {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

/********************************/
/*          Hero Headers        */
/********************************/
.hero {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
           -o-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
              transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);

}
.hero h1 {
    font-size: 5em;    
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item .hero {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item.active .hero {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;    
}

/********************************/
/*            Overlay           */
/********************************/
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #080d15;
    opacity: .7;
}

/********************************/
/*          Custom Buttons      */
/********************************/
.btn.btn-lg {padding: 10px 40px;}
.btn.btn-hero,
.btn.btn-hero:hover,
.btn.btn-hero:focus {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    border-color: #1abc9c;
    outline: none;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

/********************************/
/*       Slides backgrounds     */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1, 
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1 {
  background-image: url(../img/crabcakes.jpg); 
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2 {
  background-image: url(../img/cakeplate.jpg);
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  background-image: url(../img/drinks.jpg);
}

/********************************/
/*          Media Queries       */
/********************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 980px){
    .hero { width: 980px; }    
}

@media screen and (max-width: 440px) {
    .hero h1 {
        font-size:3.8em;
    } 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 340px) {
    .hero h1 {
        font-size:3em;
    } 
}
```

And here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Crabcake Factory | World Famous Crabcakes!</title>
   <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href="css/carouselcss.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
  </head>

  <body>
               <!--navigation -->
                <div id="navmarg">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><p>Crabcake Factory | Open 9-9PM Daily!</p></a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">


                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Online Store <span class="caret"></span></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Clothing/Accessories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>

                          </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Locations &amp; Specials, Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Locations &amp; Specials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>

                          </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                      </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                </nav>
            </div>      
          <!--END NAV-->

<!--START JUMBO SLIDER-->

<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">
  <!-- Overlay -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item slides active">
      <div class="slide-1"></div>
      <div class="hero">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Hungry?</h1>        
            <h3>We ship delicious crabcakes World Wide!</h3>
        </hgroup>
            <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Order Crabcakes</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-2"></div>
      <div class="hero">        
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Something for Everyone</h1>        
            <h3>Browse our menu!</h3>
        </hgroup>       
            <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Menu</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-3"></div>
      <div class="hero">        
        <hgroup>
                  <h1>Rockin' Specials!</h1>        
                  <h3>The Best on the Shore!</h3>
              </hgroup>
              <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Locations &amp; Specials</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> 
</div>

  <!--END JUMBO SLIDER-->


  <div class="container">

      <div class="row">


      </div>

















    </div><!--ENDCONTAINER-->

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```